# c++ // wrong output ... what is going on?

Tags: c++

please can somebody explain this to me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        sum += 24 * pow(10, 3 - j - 1);

    }

    cout << sum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This is my little program and it is printing out wrong answer (2663 instead of 2664), but when I write **1** * pow(...) instead of 24 everything is good. I am so confuse

Comment: Very simple: `pow` operates on `double`, not `int`. Hence, some values cannot be represented exactly. When converting to the result back to `int`, it may round down or up.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact results, never rely on data types that cannot store the the results in an exact way. In your case, the expression `24 * pow(10, 3 - j - 1)` has type `double`, as the return type of `pow` is `double` and the multiplication of an `int` and a `double` results in a `double`.

The correct way of writing this piece of code is to use a power function that operates on integers:

```
int pow(int base, int exponent)
{
    assert(exponent >= 0); // Design decision, you may want to support negative exponents as well
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
    {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For finding instances of such mistakes, enable warnings (e.g. in gcc it's `-Wconversion`).

Comment: `int pow(int base, int exponent)
    {
        assert(exponent >= 0);
        int result = 1, exp = 1, mask = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8 - 1; ++i)
        {
            exp *= base;
            if(exponent && mask) result *= exp;
            mask <<= 1;
        }
        return result;
    }`

Comment: @bipll Care to elaborate what you're trying to say with your comment?

Comment: Turning O(N) exponentiation into O(logN).

Comment: @bipll Well the runtime of this algorithm isn't what the question is about, it's just a quick sample implementation. And actually, I think it's fairly pointless to care about performance of this algorithms for `int`, as the maximum valid exponent for all except three cases is less than 64 anyway. By the way, it should be `exponent & mask`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, mistyped.
BTW, in case base is 1 or zero, any exponent will fit into 32bit.

Comment: @bipll Exactly, for -1, 0 and 1, any exponent is fine. But for all bases with magnitude >= 2, (assuming a 64bit integer), the exponent can only be <= 64, as any value above will result in overflow (which is undefined behavior for signed integers).

Answer (score -1):

There is no implementation of `pow()` that returns an `int`, so apparently the implementation that returns a `float` is being selected by the compiler as the default one.

The problem with `float` is that it cannot represent all numbers, it works with approximations. Which means that some of the results of this `pow()` may be not exact integer numbers as you would expect.

When you implicitly convert the result of `pow()` to `int` when trying to store it in the variable `sum`, that is of type `int`, the decimals are truncated, causing loss of information.

To prevent this loss of information, use `double` instead of `int`. When operating with `double`s, the implementation of `pow()` that returns a `double` will be used, and it shouldn't have problems to give you the correct answer, nothing will be truncated and information won't be lost.

Comment: `double` has the exact same problem as `float`. There are integers that don't have an exact representation as `double`. If the result as an integer has to be exact, it is a very bad idea to convert to any floating point number type at any time.

Comment: @stefan He doesn't have a choice, he is using `pow()`, and it will always truncate down to the closest integer when converting to `int`. The cleanest solution in this case is just accept that the library uses `double` and use it too. Alternatively, you can do the old ugly hack of doing `(int)(x + 0.5)` to make sure the number is truncated to the value you expect, but personally I'd avoid putting that on my code. Also, `double` guarantees a number of digits of precision, usually 15, which is way more than you can tell for `float`.